# Compile swiften library for iPhone sdk

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, swiften

Short description about library : [Link of library](http://swift.im/swiften/)

I want to compile swift library (i.e. http://swift.im/git/swift/tag/?id=swift-2.0beta1)  for iPhone sdk. I have checked its document folder and way of compilation but they only mentioned compilation steps  for Windows and Unix(i.e. This page contains link for compilation files http://swift.im/download/#apt). But I am not getting how to compile it for iPhone sdk. Steps that they mentioned are not getting. So, Can any one explain me ? After checking one of file i came to know that it should be possible to compile for iPhone.

One more question they mentioned that it is under GNU General public license v3 so can I use it commercial application specially apple approve it?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are trying to compile Swift or just swiften?

Comment: check this url:http://swift.im/swiften/. click on getting swiften redirecting to same url.

Comment: I have checked file "BuildingOnUnix" but not getting what to do exactly. What to do from starting. I have mac osx not unix. But I think on mac terminal we can run almost commands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figures `Swiften` already has built-in support for building for an iOS device or simulator. I was able to build it, but haven't tested it.

I will assume you z XCode 4.4 (or something sufficiently modern) and target **iOS 5.1 running on iPhone > 3GS**. Also, I will assume you want to build swiften-1.0.
(if building for earlier iPhone, change `armv7` back to `armv6` below)

There are several steps involved in order to build it.

## Fix paths and SDK version

Open `swift-1.0/BuildTools/SCons/SConstruct` in a file editor, and :

1. Change line 232 from

   `env["XCODE_PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR"] = "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin"`

   to

   `env["XCODE_PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR"] = "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents" + "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin"`
2. In line 234, change `armv6` to `armv7`
3. In line 239, change "4.0" to "5.1"
4. Change line 240 from

   `env["XCODE_SDKROOT"] = "/Developer/Platforms/" + sdkPart + ".platform/Developer/SDKs/" + sdkPart + sdkVer + ".sdk"`

   to

   `env["XCODE_SDKROOT"] = "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents" + "/Developer/Platforms/" + sdkPart + ".platform/Developer/SDKs/" + sdkPart + sdkVer + ".sdk"`

## Copy `crt_externs.h` to `swift-1.0/`

(from Matt Galloway's [Compiling Boost for the iPhone](http://www.galloway.me.uk/2009/11/compiling-boost-for-the-iphone/))

Copy `crt_externs.h` to `swift`'s directory; when in `swift-1.0/`, execute:

```
cp /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/usr/include/crt_externs.h .
```

## Download and Build `openssl`

`swiften` requires `openssl`, but iOS does not have a built-in one, so you'll have to download and compile it manually. Execute the following in a terminal:

```
cd <swift-directory>/3rdParty/OpenSSL
wget http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1c.tar.gz
```

This will download the soruce of openssl; to build it, I used a [script from GitHub](https://github.com/st3fan/ios-openssl). Still in `<swift-directory>/swift-1.0/3rdParty/OpenSSL`, execute,

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://raw.github.com/st3fan/ios-openssl/master/build.sh
```

Edit `build.sh` - change line 10 from `1.0.1b` to `1.0.1c`.

Now, `chmod +x build.sh` and finally `./build.sh`. This will take several minutes to build `openssl`.

## Build `swiften`

You're almost there - change directory to the root of `swift`, and execute

```
./scons Swiften allow_warnings=yes target=iphone-device openssl="<swift-directory>/3rdParty/OpenSSL"
```

This will build a library for linking against an application built for the device; if you want to run it in the simulator, change `target=iphone-device` to `target-iphone-simulator` in the line above. The library file `libSwiften.a` can be found in `<swift-directory>/Swiften`.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for :) Still couldn't make it work on mavericks, xcode 6. I followed every step, but during the last step, it seems it ain't finding any library (during the check logs), and it stops with `Error: Cannot find strcasemp() or stricmp()`. Any clue of what can be happenning?